# Java Lab - Counting Runs

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Langauge: Java

No syntax errors and passed the compiler but failed my tester. Anyone can tell me what I did wrong here?

Here's what the lab text states for what the method is to do: 
"counts how many runs (consecutive blocks of equal elements) there are in the subarray of arr from index start to index end , inclusive"

Also: I'm not allowed to use any loops for this lab, if-else statements are okay though.

parameters: arr = array, start/end = indices for start/end

```
public class Recursion {
    int countRuns(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) 
            return 0; //checks for null arrays 

        int counter = 0; 
        if (start == 0)
            counter = 1; 

        //check the next element for similarity/difference 
        if (arr[start] != arr[start+1])
            counter = 1; 

        return counter + countRuns(arr, start + 1, end);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just slightly missed the conditions at beginning and end.. This should work:

```
public class Recursion {
    int countRuns(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) 
            return 0; //checks for null arrays 

        if (start == end) // the indices are inclusive
            return 1;

        int counter; 
        if (arr[start] == arr[start + 1]) {
            counter = 0; // we'll still be in the same run, if they're equal
        } else {
            counter = 1; // otherwise it's a new run
        }

        return counter + countRuns(arr, start + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that totally fixed it! Could you explain where I went wrong though, I'd like to understand where did I miss and how the solution affected it? Sorry new to java coding

Comment: I can try :) So the simplest case is when `start==end`, right, just one element. You returned 0 in that case, so that was the first mistake.. In the fixed code, this case is explicitly checked for and returns 1..

Comment: The second mistake was that check for `start==0`.. Not sure what lead you to put it in there, but it looks like you wanted to do something "at the beginning". But you can tell it's a mistake because it's possible that start is never 0 at all, so you gotta do it in some other way..

Comment: And that's it, actually - I just changed the code that follows so it's more obvious, otherwise it does exactly the same thing as the original..

Comment: thanks, that makes total sense now! I guess next time I should check the code more closely before compiling. Since there were no syntax errors I didn't take a second glance at my lab code to see that little bug.

Comment: @Erebus Instead of editing the question and adding `(Solved)` to the title, you should up-vote the answer because you find it useful, **and** you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction. Accepting the answer is the right way to do it. Editing the title is not.

Comment: @Andreas, gotcha I did upvote the answer but neglected the checkmark. Just did that, thanks for letting me know. New to stack overflow, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Erebus No, you haven't upvoted it. It only has one up-vote, and that's mine. Click the up-arrow to up-vote. --- And welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: @Andreas, I did but I keep getting the following message from SO and my vote does not get added to the score. Guess I do not have enough rep yet :(. 

Thanks for the welcome! :) 


---- "thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"----

(I have a current rep of only 3 if anyone was wondering)